# Dividing negative numbers with floordiv in python

Tags: python, integer-division, negative-number

I'm confused by the nature of integer division with // or floordiv with negative numbers in python.

```
>>> -5 // 2
-3
>>> int(-5/2)
-2
```

Why would floordiv() round down to -3? I thought integer division was supposed to simply drop (or lack) the information after the decimal point.

Comment: Which version of python?

Answer (score 10):

In arithmetic, the `floor` function is defined as *the largest integer not greater than the operand*. Since the largest integer not greater than -2.5 is -3, the results you are seeing are the expected results.

I suppose a way of thinking about it is that floordiv always rounds down (toward the *left* on the numberline), but acts on the actual value of the operand (-2.5), not its absolute value (2.5).

Wikipedia has more here at [Floor and ceiling functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).

Note that the behavior you describe is provided by the `math.trunc()` function in the Python standard library.

```
>>> from math import trunc
>>> trunc(-2.5)
-2
```

Comment: Python's `Decimal` package is odd in this sense though, it behaves more like `trunc` and removes the decimal (so it behaves the same for positive numbers, but the negative numbers merely